# How to add own custom function in standard shared library (C) in linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I have downloaded libgcrypt library source code and I want to customize this standard shared library by adding my function inside one particular 
source code file .

Although compilation/build process of customized shared library is successful, but it shows error at linking time.

Here is what I have done .

inside /src/visibility.c file, I have added my custom function,

```
void MyFunction(void)
{
    printf("This is added just for testing purpose");   
}
```

I have also include function prototype inside /src/gcrypt.h

```
void MyFunction(void);


#build process

./configure --prefix=/usr
sudo make install

nm command find this custom function.

nm /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so | grep MyFunction
000000000000dd70 t MyFunction
```

Here is my sample code to access my custom function.

```
//aes_gcrypt_example.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gcrypt.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
MyFunction();
return 0;
}


gcc aes_gcrypt_example.c -o aes -lgcrypt

/tmp/ccA0qgAB.o: In function `main':
aes_gcrypt_example.c:(.text+0x3a2): undefined reference to `MyFunction'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried by making MyFunction as extern inside gcrypt.h, but in that case also I am getting same error.

**Why is this happening ?**

**Is the customization of standard library is not allowed ?**

**If YES, then is there any FLAG to disable to allow customization ?**

**If NO, what mistake I am making ?**

It would be great help if someone provide some useful link/solution for the above mentioned problem. I am using Ubuntu16.04 , gcc 4.9.

Comment: Are you sure it's linking against your customized library?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I think so as I have deleted all other .so files.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, do you have any solution ?

Comment: You really want a magic solution before you even fully understand the problem?

Comment: Build successful, nm detect the function inside customized shared library. So what can be the problem ? I don't get you what you trying to say.

Comment: The problem is that you don't know which library you're linking to.

Comment: If there is ONLY one copy of .so file, then there is no possibility of linking with other location .so file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower-case `t` for the symbol type?

> ```
> nm /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so | grep MyFunction
> 000000000000dd70 t MyFunction
> ```

Are you sure that's a visible function?  On my Ubuntu 16.04 VM, the linkable functions defined in an object file have `T` (not `t`) as the symbol type.  Is there a stray `static` kicking around and causing confusion?  Check a couple of other functions defined in `libgcrypt.so` (and documented in `gcrypt.h`) and see whether they have a `t` or a `T`.  They will have a `T` and not `t`.  You'll need to work out why your function gets a `t` — it is not clear from the code you show.

The (Ubuntu) man page for `nm` includes:

> The symbol type.  At least the following types are used; others
>    are, as well, depending on the object file format.  If lowercase,
>    the symbol is usually local; if uppercase, the symbol is global
>    (external).

The line you show says that `MyFunction` is not visible outside its source file, and the linker agrees because it is not finding it.

Your problem now is to check that the object file containing `MyFunction` has a symbol type `T` — if it doesn't the problem is in the source code.

Assuming that the object file shows symbol type `T` but the shared object shows symbol type `t`, you have to find what happens during the shared object creation phase to make the symbol invisible outside the shared object.  This is probably because of a 'linker script' that controls which symbols are visible outside the library (or maybe just compilation options).  You can search on Google with 'linker script' and various extra words ('tutorial', 'provide', 'example', etc) and come up with links to the relevant documentation.

You may need to research documentation for [LibTool](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/), or for the linker [BinUtils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/). LibTool provides ways of manipulating shared libraries. In a compilation command line that you show in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708185/how-to-add-own-custom-function-in-standard-shared-library-c-in-linux/48710113?noredirect=1#comment84420352_48710113), there is the option `-fvisibility=hidden`. I found (mostly by serendipitous accident) a GCC Wiki on [visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility). See also [visibility attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-visibility-function-attribute) and [code generation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options).

Comment: even with extern keyword before MyFunction (extern void MyFunction(void); inside gcrypt.h) nm returns t (not T) ,and also it gives same error undefined reference to `MyFunction'.

Comment: So you need to look rather carefully at how the library is converted from `.o` files into a `.so`.  Maybe the process defines exactly which symbols are exported and since yours is not in that list, it is made invisible from outside the library.  You'd need to look for a linker script — that's the terminology (Google search for tutorials, etc).  The problem is the `t` instead of `T`; the cause of that I'm not sure of, and consequently I'm not sure of the fix, either.  That is mostly for you to track down.  (You won't be able to link to the function until it is tagged `T` and not `t`.)

Comment: I agree with you that nm should return T to be accessible from outside, however in my case it always returns t.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will look into the shared library linker script (don't know what is the file name) to find how symbols are exported .

Comment: Start by checking the symbol letter in the object file.  If it is `T` there (I expect it is) but `t` in the shared object (it seems to be), then the problem is in the transition from object file to shared object — aka the linking process.

Comment: Surprisingly there is no object file(.o, even .libs/libgcrypt_la-visibility.o doesn't exist ) . Although make process generates .libs/libgcrypt_la-visibility.o ( I capture make output to know name of object file). libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -MT libgcrypt_la-visibility.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgcrypt_la-visibility.Tpo -c visibility.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libgcrypt_la-visibility.o

Comment: You may need to research documentation for [LibTool](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/), or for the linker ([BinUtils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/).  LibTool provides ways of manipulating shared libraries.  Have fun chasing it down.  You now know the immediate source of your problem.  You know you have to trace through the building process to find out where what happens that your function becomes invisible.  I'll delete this answer if you want me to — I'm trying to get you on the road, even though I don't have the complete answer.

Comment: Thank you so much . I think your suggestion to explore LibTool/BinUtils may be fruitful to understand the magic happening for generating external/local symbol in shared library. As you rightly point out the t(T), main reason behind the inaccessible from outside, I am accepting the answer although it is not complete answer, it gives insight.

Comment: I notice that your command line includes `-fvisibility=hidden`.  I found (mostly by serendipitous accident) a GCC Wiki on [Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).  See also [visibility attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-visibility-function-attribute) and [code generation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options).